# Hide list items until click next

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a multi step form. I just want to show the first step active and other list items disable(that means user can see other list items but cannot click) If he fills out the first step then he can click next and go to second step. I have already added the active state. But I'm stuck with link disable part.

```js
/*Active state*/

$('ul.post-ad-active a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('active-post');

$('ul.post-ad-active a').filter(function() {
  return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active-post');
```

```css
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="other-links">
  <ul class="post-ad-active">
    <li>
      <a href="job-basic-details">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&emsp;Basic details
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="job-images">
        <i class="fa fa-camera fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&emsp;Images
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="job-contact-and-status">
        <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&emsp;Contact and status
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: please add your code in fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this,that is you could return false onclick of the anchor tag and then add the class ,i have changed the styles as well in the css

```js
$("a[href='job-images']").on("click",false).css('cursor', 'default').addClass("disabled");
```

```css
.disabled {
     cursor: default;
     opacity: 0.6;
  text-decoration:none
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="other-links">
            <ul class="post-ad-active">
                <li>
                    <a href="job-basic-details">
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&emsp;Basic details
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="job-images">
                        <i class="fa fa-camera fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&emsp;Images
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="job-contact-and-status">
                        <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&emsp;Contact and status
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```